# phonegap-plugin-push not triggering callback function for new notification when app is in foreground

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm writing a mobile app for Android using Phonegap (cli v5.3.6) and I'm using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) v1.3 for registering the device with GCM and handling the notifications as they arrive at the device.

```
// define the push settings
var push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": {
        "senderID": "*********"
    },
    "ios": {},
    "windows": {}
});

push.on("notification", function(data) {
    console.log("notification received while in app");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    addMessageToLocalDB(data, false);
});
push.on("error", function(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

It works well when the app is either closed or in the background. My problem occurs when the app is in the foreground. I'm looking at the logcat and see that the notification is received, but I'm not seeing my logging to show that the callback function is fired (and obviously, the outcome I'm expecting to see isn't happening). I'm also not seeing the callback function of the error event firing, so it probably isn't really failing.

Am I missing something? I couldn't find anything online about this problem and I can't really read java to understand how the plugin is supposed to behave...

- Edit: I just figured out something. The logs that indicate on the arrival of the push notification occur even if I remove the code from my javascript - the PushNotification init and on("notificataion") functions.
  I'm therefore finding myself a bit confused as to where I need to place the init and event handler functions.

My app consists of index.html (which is the page that loads when the app starts) and many other html files (which each act as a separate page of the app. Shouldn't I put the event handler on each individual page? That what I did try...

Thanks,
Yosi.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to wait for the `deviceready` event, before calling `PushNotification.init`. This might be more reliable (and quicker) than using `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

I might not get your questuion but if you want to show notification when the app is in foreground .The default value for forceshow parameter is false and you are right it's n't failing

"android": {
        "senderID": "*********",
        "forceShow" : "true"
    },

Answer (score 0):

I eventually noticed that the PushNotification object is sometimes undefined when I first load the page, but then if I wait enough time (100ms), it is then defined.
What I ended up doing is an interval to run every 100ms, check if the PushNotification object is defined and if so, run my init+event listener code and clear the interval. This seems to be working well for quite some time.

Comment: Setting an interval to run every 100 ms is not at all a good idea and is an unnecessary overhead for the application. You should rather wait for the deviceready event to be fired first then initialize Push Notification object. And register it for notification and error callbacks. Any device once registered through the App will receive notification for any number of times unless the App is uninstalled. Infact there is no need to register the device every now and then, registering for Push Notification once is enough!